# How to multiply with sum in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to multiply sales.price with merchants.commission with Laravel Query Builder. Currently my query looks like this, but I unfortunately do not know what do proceed. Help is kindly appreciated.

```
DB::table('sales')
->leftJoin('merchants', 'sales.merchant', '=', 'merchant.id')
->sum("");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually pass a `DB::raw()` expression to select the sum of much more than just a column. For example:

```
$total = DB::table('sales')
           ->leftJoin('merchants', 'sales.merchant', '=', 'merchant.id')
           ->sum(DB::raw('sales.price * merchants.commission'));
```